# In matplotlib how do I put xticks as exponents and unlabeled ticks in between

Tags: python, matplotlib

This code is working for me but I want to know if I can make it better.

```
plt.plot(range(2,len(data)+2), data, marker = 'o',  mfc = 'red')
plt.xticks(range(2,len(percen_nonzero_runs)+2),
       ['$10^{2}$', '','', '','$10^{3}$','','','', '$10^{4}$','','','',
        '$10^{5}$','','','','$10^{6}$','','','' ])
sns.despine(right=True, top=True)
plt.ylabel("Probability")
plt.xlabel("Sampling size")
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot is this
[image]

If possible I do not want the tick in between the major ticks. May be one single tick like $5 \times 10^2$ between $10^2$ and $10^3$.

Comment: Why don't you plot using the actual x values and use a logarithmic scale for the x-axis?

Answer (score 1):

We are missing an example database that mimic yours so we can test the code so I'm not entirely sure everything is right.

However it should work by changing the range step, instead of 1 you should put 4 if you want just the major ones (removing the `''`), something like:

```
plt.xticks(range(2,len(percen_nonzero_runs)+2,4),
           [r'$10^{2}$',r'$10^{3}$',r'$10^{4}$',r'$10^{5}$',r'$10^{6}$'])
```

or if you want the "mid" ticks you should use a step equal to two, something like:

```
plt.xticks(range(2,len(percen_nonzero_runs)+2,2),
           [r'$10^{2}$',r'$5 \times 10^2$',r'$10^{3}$',r'$5 \times 10^3$',
            r'$10^{4}$',r'$5 \times 10^4$',r'$10^{5}$',r'$5 \times 10^5$',
            r'$10^{6}$',r'$5 \times 10^6$'])
```